# Multiple Checkbox create LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have 4 checkboxes and based on which ones the user clicks on, I need to produce the LINQ statement. As mentioned below in the comment section, if I select just one checkbox, it works fine. If I select multiple checkboxes, it returns 0 results.

The 4 checkboxes are 1) "Item1" 2) "Item2" 3) "Item3" 4) "Item4".

This is what I have far:

```
        var entity = _w_ItemRepository.GetMany(p => p.ID == id);  

         /* If I select just one item it works fine. If I select multiple items get 0 result */

          entity = entity.Where
            (p => (p.ItemType == 1 || !item1)
               && (p.ItemType == 2 || !item2)
               && (p.ItemType == 2 || !item3)
               && (p.ItemType == 3 || !item4)
           );
```

Comment: Store the checked items in a array  named arr

var entity = _w_ItemRepository.Where(x=>arr.Contains(x.id))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the `&&`s need to be `||`s.  Consider if both `item1` and `item2` are `true` then you're essentially saying:

```
.Where(p => p.ItemType == 1 && p.ItemType == 2)
```

When the intent is probably:

```
.Where(p => p.ItemType == 1 || p.ItemType == 2)
```

(It also looks like there's a typo, you specify `ItemType == 2` twice.)

Try:

```
entity = entity.Where
        (p => (p.ItemType == 1 || !item1)
           || (p.ItemType == 2 || !item2)
           || (p.ItemType == 3 || !item3)
           || (p.ItemType == 4 || !item4)
       );
```

Or I think this may be more clear, adding each clause if `itemX` is `true`:

```
entity = entity.Where
        (p => (item1 && p.ItemType == 1)
           || (item2 && p.ItemType == 2)
           || (item3 && p.ItemType == 3)
           || (item4 && p.ItemType == 4)
       );
```